# Where does the reaction force go when we slip?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction

I have been trying to wrap my head around friction and how it works and I sort of cant understand the concept of slipping.

When I walk I push the ground backwards and hence the ground pushes me forwards (which is the friction force)

Hence friction is what makes me move forward.

However on a slippery plane when I walk forward, doesn't the plane also apply a force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction, hence making me move forward.

Why do I slip? Shouldn't I be moving forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However on a slippery plane when I walk forward, doesn't the plane
> also apply a force equal in magnitude and opposite in direction, hence
> making me move forward.

Unless the plane is totally frictionless, there will still be kinetic (sliding) friction. You will still be applying a force backwards on the plane and the plane exerting an equal and opposite force forwards on you, but the force will be less since kinetic friction is generally less than static friction. Hence you may still accelerate forward but at a slower rate than when you are not slipping and the friction was static. An example is a car that attempts to accelerate too quickly and loses traction. The car still moves forward but at a much slower rate and with the wheels spinning ("burning rubber" as they say.)

On the other hand, if the plane was frictionless, when you push your leg backwards there would be no friction force to oppose it and act forward. It would be equivalent to moving your foot backwards without touching the surface. Taking the car example, if the road were frictionless (or close to it) the wheel would spin in place and there would be little or no movement forward of the car.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Frictional force opposes the relative motion between two surfaces and it is directly proportional to the normal reaction. It also depends on the nature of the surface.

When you try to walk on a regular (rough) surface, the static friction helps to keep your foot in place as you apply a force on the surface. This is because the horizontal component of the applied force would be less than the limiting static friction and so you would not slip. The frictional force will match and oppose the component of your applied force along the surface as long as it is lower than the maximum value of static friction (the maximum being coefficient of static friction multiplied by the normal reaction).

If the surface becomes wet, the coefficient of friction decreases, and you would no longer be able to hold your foot in place as the frictional force offered by the surface would be lower than the horizontal component of the applied force.

So when you slip, it does not mean that the reaction force vanishes. It merely means that the frictional force offered by the surface was not enough to keep your foot in place.

Comment: If the static friction is always greater than the backward force I apply on the surface, then how do I even apply a backward force on the surface? Won't my foot begin to move forward, where the frictional force is acting? Or will it not even move at all

Comment: Static friction is actually a self adjusting type of force. It matches the applied force upto a maximum value called limiting friction. Suppose a surface has a maximum limiting friction of 20N. If you apply a force of 15N, then the frictional force would match that 15N in the opposite direction. If you apply say 25N, then the maximum friction offered by the surface would still be 20 and so the body would experience a net force of 5N in the direction of the applied force.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your question is the following:

> Your foot exerts a force on the surface and the surface hence responds with a friction reaction force as per Newton's 3rd law. On the slippery surface, your foot still exerts this force but now suddenly there is *no* friction reaction force!? But shouldn't there always be a reaction force according to Newton's 3rd law?

Have I understood this correctly? If so, then the problem here in the slippery case is that *your foot in fact does **not** exert a force on the surface at all*! Sure, your foot is moving. But that is due to forces from without body and muscles. The foot is *not* exerting external forces into the surface. Thus there is no action for friction to react to - so friction does not appear. And Newton's 3rd law still holds true.

---

Now, just for completeness let me mention: Your foot *does* exert a force on the surface *vertically*. And that causes a normal force to come into existence to balance it out. But there is no *horizontal* force exerted by the foot, and thus no friction force, which is what you are asking to. In general reaction forces are constituted by normal forces in perpendicular directions and friction forces in tangential directions, and slippery/smooth surfaces show no tangential reaction forces.