# If static friction is always greater than the force I apply on the ground while walking, how do we even move forward?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, free-body-diagram

> Force occurs in pairs, i.e action and reaction are simultaneous. When you push the ground, the ground simultaneously exerts a reaction force. This reaction force does not depend on friction. Now, frictional force opposes the relative motion between two surfaces and it is directly proportional to the normal reaction. It also depends on the nature of the surface. When you try to walk on a regular surface, the static friction helps to keep your foot in place as you apply a force on the surface. This is because the horizontal component of the applied force would be less than the static friction and so you would not slip. If the surface becomes wet, the coefficient of friction decreases, and you would no longer be able to hold your foot in place as the frictional force offered by the surface would be lower than the horizontal component of the applied force. So when you slip, it does not mean that the reaction force vanishes. It merely means that the frictional force offered by the surface was not enough to keep your foot in place.

The text above was [an answer I received](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/789891/78287) while trying to clear up how friction comes into play while we walk. However there is still something that is not clear to me.

> This is because the horizontal component of the applied force would be less than the static friction and so you would not slip

If the static friction is always greater than the backward force I apply on the surface, then how do I even apply a backward force on the surface? Won't my foot begin to move forward, where the frictional force is acting? Or will it not even move at all. Since the frictional force is greater than the backward force I apply on the surface, the net force will either be 0 or some negative number (which represents a net force in the direction where the frictional force is acting)

Comment: I find the  introductory statement totally confusing.

Comment: TLDR: when they said, "...less than the static friction," they meant, "...less than the amount of force that would _break_ the static friction." Same as saying, "...less than the product of your weight and the coefficient of static friction between your shoes and the ground."

Comment: [Previous answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/789891/81133) from which this question is quoting.

Comment: That's why we're lifting our legs when walking. The foot on the ground is held firmly in place by friction (or not so firmly when there's ice on the street), while the other foot is moving. Try walking without lifting your leg and see what friction does to you.

Answer (score 8):

Our feet do not slide forward when we walk. When we take a step we use the stable foot (which does not slide because of static friction), as a fixed point to pull against until our center of mass is past the foot and then we push against that stable point (this pull + push is what is changing our momentum in the direction of the walking, the foot itself is planted on the ground and prevented in sliding by friction).

Once we are sufficiently past the planted foot, we plant another foot (this usually happens in one motion of simultaneously planting the other foot and pushing forward) and then we lift the original foot. In lifting the original foot the motion of the foot itself is mostly vertical (from heel to toe) lifting OFF the ground, not sliding along it. Once completely airborne where there is no (or negligible I should say) friction then we extend this foot we just lifted forward to plant it again onto the ground ahead of us.

Static friction does not prevent us from walking because when we walk our feet never slide across the ground. We are actually pulling and pushing our bodies over our planted feet and then just in time, LIFTING and planting our feet so we do not fall.

Comment: Nonetheless, to get *started* walking, there must be net force on a person directed forward so that there is an acceleration forward, and this net force is essentially the static friction force that the ground exerts on our foot.  Ignoring the complicated mechanics of a non-rigid object such as our bodies, there is an external force--static friction--that is kinematically leading to our forward acceleration.

Comment: Yea so starting from a deadstill, we lean forward shifting our center-of-mass infront of us, this action is our body leaning forward and legs sliding back, where static friction prevents the latter from happening, so we only move our center of mass forward, now our legs are behind us, so if we sufficiently quickly lift and place them in front of us, we wont fall and then the analysis I gave above explains how we do the rest of the walking

Comment: This initial lean forward we do to get moving is closely tied to the static friction preventing our feet from sliding underneath us. if the ground below was completely slippery and we had a rope to prevent us from from falling we would just lean forward while sliding our feet back, and then slide our feet forward and lean back and would simply not move just sliding back and forth. We can imagine if the slippery ground suddenly become a high friction surface, we would instantly propel forward (or backward). It now becomes clear the role the friction plays in allowing us to move.

Answer (score 6):

The force provided by static friction $F=\mu N$ represents an *upper limit* of what the reactionary force can provide - friction never acts on its own, but only in opposition to another force. To say that static friction is greater than the force your foot applies isn't quite right, as that would indeed imply that friction alone could cause something to spontaneously move. It would be more correct to say that the *upper limit* of the frictional force is greater than the force applied by your foot - the *actual* frictional force is only as large as it needs to be to oppose your foot pushing backward, and no bigger. As you push harder and harder with your foot, the frictional force increases to match so that your foot remains static. At some point, you may push so hard that the applied force exceeds the maximum frictional force, in which case your foot will slide backwards.

Comment: So how do we move forward?

Comment: @ShaharyarAhmed A wheel also experiences friction, can you see how a wheel rolls?

Comment: @ShaharyarAhmed when we walk our feet remain stationary. It's friction that holds our foot stationary. Walking is basically changing the shape of our bodies while one foot remains stationary

Answer (score 2):

> If the static friction is always greater than the backward force I apply on the surface

Static friction will be equal to the backward force you apply on the ground, not greater than.

> then how do I even apply a backward force on the surface?

By pushing your foot backwards with your muscles.

> Won't my foot begin to move forward, where the frictional force is acting?

Your entire body will begin to move forward, which is the whole point of walking.

> the net force will either be 0 or some negative number

This isn't really what we do when we talk about net force - you shouldn't add two forces that are **acting on different objects**.

The forward force of the ground is only acting on you, so you move forward. The backward force of your foot only acts on the ground, so the ground moves backward (barely).

Comment: When I talk about net force I am referring to the frictional force and the force that my foot applies when walking. When I apply the backward force, the frictional force, as you said will be equal in magnitude to that force. So won't they just cancel out causing me to stay stationary

Comment: @ShaharyarAhmed No. The force you are applying with you foot is being applied  _on the ground_, not on yourself. The frictional force is what the   ground applies back on _you_. Were you to draw a diagram showing all the forces on your body (an FBD),  there would be only one force on you in the horizontal direction, which would be the frictional force.

Comment: @ShaharyarAhmed that's like saying if someone gives you \$10, you don't get any richer because the other person just lost $10.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be careful what you're treating as a mechanical system in your scenario.

If you consider your whole body as one system, your center of mass will accelerate forward, but the individual part (your foot) of the system (your whole body) can have arbitrary motion relative to the center of mass. So it's totally possible to have your feet remain stationary, while your body as a whole is accelerating forward.

If you want to dig into details of how your foot remains stationary, you need to consider your foot and the rest of your body as separate systems. The forces acting of the foot will be a friction from the ground and a force from your connective tissues, which balance out.

Answer (score 0):

For every action there is an equal and opposite reaction.  Your foot pushes against the ground and your body moves forward.  Your foot will not slip until the force that you apply to the ground is greater than the calculated static friction which until the point that it is exceeded is an equal and opposite force to your foot.